# How can I log the running duration of multiple excel power queries while still returning the query tables?

Tags: excel, powerquery, timing

I am looking for a way to record the timings of multiple queries running in excel.

Preferably I would like all queries to refresh using refresh all then produce a separate table with the query names and duration of running time per query.

I have tried two methods currently but neither are doing exactly what I want:

## **Method 1**

*Time within the table*

**Source**
https://eriksvensen.wordpress.com/2018/05/15/time-your-power-queries-powerbi-powerquery/

**Result**
This method didn't seem to work because apparently excel doesn't run the steps in the order noted on the right side of the query editor so the timings recorded at the start and end of the query was only a few seconds different when in real time they could be minutes apart.

## **Method 2**

*Time outside of table*

**Source**
https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2014/11/17/timing-power-query-queries/

**Result**
This method seemed to work accurately but I couldn't find a way to add the time to the table without duplicating the query therefore doubling the real time to refresh.

Can anyone think of a way I can produce what I am after, either via a different method or by adjusting one of the above methods?

EDIT:

I think perhaps my only option would be to create a macro that refreshes each query individually by name, storing the time before and after each refresh as variables then to put these figures into a table once complete.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar. I have used VBA like you suggested, but have ran into an issue where excel will cache the outputs if ran multiple times in a row. Beware of that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78015976/how-to-force-power-query-to-clear-caches-to-get-accurate-performance-metrics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best method I could come up with to achieve my goal was to write VBA that refreshed each query by name and stored the results in a table.

This is the code I created...

ListConnectons (To find the names to use in the next macro):

```
Sub ListConnections()
Dim cn As WorkbookConnection
Debug.Print "Name", "|", "Description", "|", "|", "RefreshWithRefreshAll", "|", "InModel", "|", "Type"

For Each cn In ThisWorkbook.Connections
Debug.Print cn.Name, "|", cn.Description, "|", cn.RefreshWithRefreshAll, "|", cn.InModel, "|", cn.Type
Next
End Sub
```

Query Timer (To run 2 queries and store times in a table):

```
Sub QueryTimer()

    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim EndTime As Double

'##################
'##### Query 1 ####
'##################

    Dim Query1 As Double
    
    StartTime = Timer
    Workbooks("workbook.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value = StartTime 
    Workbooks("workbook.xlsx").Connections("Query - Query 1").Refresh

    EndTime = Timer
    Workbooks("workbook.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value = EndTime

    Query1 = Round(Round(EndTime - StartTime, 2) / 60, 2)

    Workbooks("workbook.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Value = Query1

'##################
'##### Query 2 ####
'##################

    Dim Query2 As Double
    
    StartTime = Timer
    Workbooks("workbook.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value = StartTime
    Workbooks("workbook.xlsx").Connections("Query - Query 2").Refresh

    EndTime = Timer
    Workbooks("workbook.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3").Value = EndTime

    Query2 = Round(Round(EndTime - StartTime, 2) / 60, 2)

    Workbooks("workbook.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D3").Value = Query2

'##################

    '#### Finished ####
    Dim TotalTime As Double

    TotalTime = Workbooks("workbook.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D4").Value
    
    MsgBox "Refresh completed in " & Format(TotalTime, "0.0") & " Minutes."

End Sub
```